# Is that possible to set prototype of a javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I want to add property "name" to child object

```
  var parent =new Object()
  parent.name="raymond"

  var child=new Object();
  child.prototype=parent;
  child.name //undefined , not work...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Comment: There's a (currently) non-standard property that lets you change the prototype of an existing object if that's really what you're asking. Not supported in all environments though.

Comment: Objects inherit from their constructor's prototype property via a hidden [`[[Prototype]]` property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2), not a public `prototype` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
var child = Object.create(parent);
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)